# Doctrine Query problem

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Hey I have some problems creating my query into doctrine:

My sql query looks like this:

```
select *
from fs_employee
where role_id = ?
and
id not in
(select e.id
from fs_employee e, fs_plane p
where role_id = ?
and p.pilot_id = e.id
and e.player_id = ?
)
```

So bassicaly I want to select every pilot employee with role_id = 20 that has not been assigned to a plane.

My doctrine query:

```
Doctrine_Query::Create()
->from('FsEmployee e')
->where('e.role_id = ?', $role)
->andWhere('e.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM FsEmployee e, e.FsPlane p where e.role_id = ? and e.player_id = ?', $role, $id)
->execute();
```

My error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\sxampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Query\Tokenizer.php on line 329
```

Thanks for helping me out,
David

Comment: You forgot a closing `)` in the subquery. No idea if this causes the performance struggly since the query is not that huge.

Comment: @DrColossos that's almost definitely the case, since the error is being thrown by the Tokenizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that my comment and the response by *jeremiahd* are identifying the problem, I will write it here again:

You forgot a closing `)` in your subquery. It should look like:

```
->andWhere('e.id NOT IN (SELECT e.id FROM FsEmployee e, e.FsPlane p where e.role_id = ? and e.player_id = ?)', $role, $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding ->limit(20) ento your entry to get first 20 entries or use sfDoctrinePager in Symfony(if you use it) to process other entries. There is also built-in [Doctrine_Pager](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/utilities) in Doctrine.

PS. try using Doctrine_Query::getSqlQuery() to get raw SQL query.